# Convergence of interesting series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Study the convergence of series:
$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left( \sqrt[n]{a}-\frac{\sqrt[n]{b}+\sqrt[n]{c}}{2} \right)$
depending on $a,b,c>0$. I have no idea how to do it, first time I see series with three parameters.

Comment: If three parameters bother you, maybe try $\sum \sqrt[n]a-\sqrt[n]b$.  $a,b$ need to be close for this not to diverge.  Do they have to be equal?

Comment: In Ross's simplified version, try $a=1$, $b=1+\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce $t_n=\sqrt[n]{a}-\frac12\sqrt[n]{b}-\frac12\sqrt[n]{c}$. For every fixed positive $x$, when $n\to\infty$,
$$
\sqrt[n]{x}=\exp\left(\frac1n\log x\right)=1+\frac1n\log x+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right).
$$
Hence $t_n=\frac1n\tau+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$  when $n\to\infty$, with $\tau=\log a-\frac12\log b-\frac12\log c=\frac12\log\left(\frac{a^2}{bc}\right)$. Since the series $\sum\limits_n\frac1n$ is divergent and the series $\sum\limits_n\frac1{n^2}$ is absolutely convergent, two cases may occur:

- If $\tau\ne0$, that is, if $a^2\ne bc$, then the series $\sum\limits_nt_n$ diverges, to $+\infty$ if $a^2\gt bc$ and to $-\infty$ if $a^2\lt bc$.
- If $\tau=0$, that is, if $a^2=bc$, then the series $\sum\limits_nt_n$ converges absolutely.